# How to delete a table in GCP BigQuery which has spaces in its filename

Tags: google-bigquery

Accidentally my python script has made a table with name as "ext_data_content_modec --replace" which we want to delete.

However BQ doesn't seem to recognize the table with spaces and keywords(--replace).

We have tried many variants of bq rm , as well as tried deleting the from BQ console but it doesn't work

For example, see below (etlt_dsc is dataset name).

```
$ bq rm 'etlt_dsc.ext_data_content_modec --replace'
BigQuery error in rm operation: Not found: Table boeing-prod-atm-next-dsc:etlt_dsc.ext_data_content_modec --replace
```

Besides above we tried below commands but nothing worked

```
bq rm "etlt_dsc.ext_data_content_modec --replace"
bq rm [etlt_dsc.ext_data_content_modec --replace]
bq rm [etlt_dsc.ext_data_content_modec --replace']
bq rm etlt_dsc.ext_data_content_modec \--replace
```

Would anyone has input for us please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$ bq ls mydataset
              tableId                Type    Labels   Time Partitioning   Clustered Fields
 ---------------------------------- ------- -------- ------------------- ------------------
  ext_data_content_modec --replace   TABLE

$
$ bq rm "mydataset.ext_data_content_modec --replace"
rm: remove table 'data-lab:mydataset.ext_data_content_modec --replace'? (y/N) y
$
$ bq ls mydataset
$
```

Comment: Looks like, you have tried this option, but I have added the steps in the post to illustrate !

Comment: Thanks for your response.....but this solution didn't help.
However we were able to 'drop' the table as workaround.

Comment: Can you please share what issue you have faced while implementing this solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the solution.
'removal' didn't work but we were able to 'drop' the table from BQ console.

Comment: Can you elaborate how it worked now and didn't worked earlier? As per your note `We have tried many variants of bq rm , as well as tried deleting the from BQ console but it doesn't work`